# Problema de carga infinita cuando intento crear un proyecto en Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android-studio

Me explico, descargué la versión de Android Studio 3.0.1 todo fue bien con la instalación descargué todo lo que me pedía, pero el problema es que cuando quiero crear un proyecto nunca construye el proyecto no puedo entrar ni a la interfaz del IDE.

Cabe resaltar que mi computadora tiene 8GB de RAM, un i5-7200U y una tarjeta gráfica NVidia 940MX, no creo que sea porque mi computadora no tenga los requisitos, quisiera saber qué puedo hacer en este caso.La verdad soy nuevo utilizando este IDE, de antemano gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: has probado la solucion que dan [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37474669/android-studio-stuck-on-loading-screen)?

Comment: Dani, en este caso el problema es el Gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Información sacada de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47110696/android-studio-3-0-stuck-at-building-gradle-project-info)

Solución :

1). Borrar la carpeta C:\Users\username.gradle

2). Descargar el siguiente archivo http://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip

3). Crea un nuevo proyecto de Android Studio.

4). Cuando se quede bloqueado buildeando el gradle, fuerza el cierre de Android Studio.

5) Ahora ves a C:\Users\username.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\c64ydeuardnfqctvr1gm30w53 (El nombre del directorio final puede ser diferente)

6) Borra gradle-2.2.1-all.zip.lck y el resto de ficheros de la carpeta.

7) Pega la nueva carpeta descargada gradle-4.2.1-all.zip here.

8) Abre Android Studio. :)

Como aportación personal, supongo que tu usuario es administrador de la maquina y has probado a ejecutar Android Studio como Administrador no?

Te agradeceremos que si te funciona la solución marques la respuesta como buena, igual que si no te funciona expliques lo que ha pasado al hacer la comprobación por favor ^_^

Comment: Si la respuesta es correcta deberias marcarla como tal a la izquierda, debajo de las flechitas ^_^

Answer (score -1):

Un archivo corrupto provoca este problema, en este caso te sugiero eliminar la configuración actual de gradle, la cual se encuentra en :

```
\users<username>\.gradle
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.